# git-lfs.windows-v.3.2.0. setup won't open

Tags: git-lfs

When trying to open the git-lfs installation setup, it shows the following error: "Could not found Git, can not register Git lfs."
Not sure if it makes any difference, I have GitHub desktop installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git LFS requires Git to be installed to work properly, and on Windows, the installer requires `git.exe` to be in the `PATH`.  Typically, the easiest way to use Git LFS on Windows is just to install Git for Windows and select Git LFS as an option when installing, since Git LFS is bundled with Git for Windows.